# How can I track previous responses?

Tags: discord.js, setinterval

I'm working on a discord bot for a D&D game. I want the bot to be able to recognize when someone has recently used a command. This is what I have so far;

```
    const barid = require("./tavernarray.json")
    var tavernarray = barid.guests;
    
    message.channel.send('Tavern Keeper Emotes and replies;')

    if (message.member.roles.cache.has('770678762944725003')){
        if (tavernarray.includes(message.author.id)){
            message.channel.send("Weren't you just here?");
        } else;
            tavernarray.push(message.author.id);
            message.channel.send(` Welcome to the Tavern Guild Master ${message.author}`);
            setInterval (() => {
                tavernarray.pop(message.author.id)
            }, 30000)

    } else {
         message.channel.send("Error no role");
    }
```

From what I can tell the code works in that on the first command, we get the welcome message expected and the user ID is added to the array. On the second command though, there's a short delay and then we get both messages. Should I be using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`? Or is it an issue with using a .json array? I tried keeping the array in the program, but it just kept resetting every time I ran it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be using `setTimeout()`. The reason you might have an issue is because the code is trying to remove the variable from the JSON array every 30 seconds which will cause two issues: higher memory usage and potential errors. The difference between `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` is `timeout` executes the function *once*, whilst the other loops continuously until it is told to break. Along with this, the way you're using `else` is the issue. When you use `else;` (Take into note the semi colon), you're telling the code that if the ID isn't there, it shouldn't execute any code, as a semi colon indicates the end of a line of code. A snippet is shown below

```js
if (tavernarray.includes(message.author.id)){
    message.channel.send("Weren't you just here?");
} else { // Instead of ; we'll use {}
    tavernarray.push(message.author.id);
    message.channel.send(` Welcome to the Tavern Guild Master ${message.author}`);
    setInterval (() => {
        tavernarray.pop(message.author.id)
    }, 30000)
}
```

Comment: I made the change, and its running a little smoother it seems, but I still have the issue where it still executes both parts of the loop. I added in a message.channel.send(`${tavernarray}) before and after the loop and this is what I see;
First time; Empty array, Welcome message, the member ID. Second time; Member ID, "Werent' you here" "Welcome" MemberID, twice. 

I feel like I've messed up the If/else loop, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I've edited my answer and it fixes the issue you are having now. If it answers your question, make sure to tick the checkmark to show others it helped you